# Rust: apply the function to each element of vector

Tags: rust

Given the following function:

```
fn some_function<K, F: Fn(K) -> K>(f: F, vs: Vec<K>) -> Vec<K> {
    let mut index = 0;
    let new_vec = vs.iter().map(|x| {
        index += 1;
        for _ in 1 .. index {
            x = f(x); // <- error here: mismatched types expected reference `&K` found type parameter `K`
        }
        *x
    }).collect();
    new_vec
}
```

How can i make it work ?

Comment: Do you really intend to apply the function `index - 1` times to each element?

Comment: I don't understand the goal of the iteration over 1..index if you only use the last value of x recalculation.

Comment: Yes, I have to apply the function i times to `i-th` element

Comment: [x, x, x] => [x, f(x), f(f(x))]

Comment: @Ali: In such a case, you have an off-by-one error I believe. `1..index` iterates `index - 1` times, and `index` is 0-based, thus you have 0 iterations at index 0 and 1, 1 iteration at index 2, 2 iterations at index 3, etc... You should use `0..index` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example doesn't work because `.iter()` will not produce an iterator of owned variables, but references to elements of `vs`. You could patch your code by turning it into `into_iter()`:

```rust
fn some_function<K>(f: impl Fn(K) -> K, vs: Vec<K>) -> Vec<K> {
    let mut index = 0;
    vs.into_iter()
    .map(|mut x| {
        index += 1;
        for _ in 1..index { x = f(x); }
        x
    })
    .collect()
}
```

But you don't need to keep track of `index`:

```rust
fn some_function<K>(f: impl Fn(K) -> K, vs: Vec<K>) -> Vec<K> {
    vs
    .into_iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, mut x)| {
        for _ in 0..i { x = f(x); }
        x
    })
   .collect()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 types of variables in Rust:

- Values.
- Shared References.
- Mutable References.

In turn, this maps to 3 different iteration functions:

- `.into_iter()` will return an iterator over values.
- `.iter()` will return an iterator over shared references.
- `.iter_mut()` will return an iterator over mutable references.

You simply didn't pick the right function, and should have used `into_iter` instead.

```rust
fn some_function<K, F: Fn(K) -> K>(f: F, vs: Vec<K>) -> Vec<K> {
    vs
        .into_iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(index, mut x)| {
            for _ in 0..index {
                x = f(x);
            }
            x
        }).collect()
}
```

Additionally:

- `enumerate` will allow you to get an index of each element as you iterate, so that you do not have to maintain the index yourself.
- To iterate `i` items, you want `0..i`, not `1..i`.

For performance, however, it would be better to *in-place* modify the elements if possible. This allows reusing buffers, including the vector's own buffer. The result would be:

```rust
fn some_function<K, F: Fn(&mut K)>(f: F, vs: &mut Vec<K>) {
    vs
        .iter_mut()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(index, x)| {
            for _ in 0..index {
                f(x);
            }
        });
}
```